# Temporal train-test split for forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I know this may be a basic question but I want to know if I am using the train, test split correctly.

Say I have data that ends at 2019, and I want to predict values in the next 5 years.

The graph I produced is provided below:
[image]

My training data starts from 1996-2014 and my test data starts from 2014-2019. The test data perfectly fits the training data. I then used this test data to make predictions from 2019-2024.

Is this the correct way to do it, or my predictions should also be from 2014-2019 just like the test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test/validation data is useful for you to evaluate the predictor to use. Once you have decided which model to use, you should train the model with the whole dataset 1996-2019 so that you do not lose possible valuable knowledge from 2014-2019. Take into account that when working with time-series, usually the newer part of the serie has more importance in your prediction than older values of the serie.

Comment: But it may lead to overfitting of the model

Comment: It should not if you chose the right model and parameters. You should use the train/test data to fine and tune a model so that it gets the best performance without overfitting. I don't know which machine learning technique are you using but, for instance, if you have an RNN, you try different training parameters, you see that with 50 epochs you get good results but with 100 epochs it starts to overfit, you should take this knowledge into account when training your final model. We assume it will have an analogous behaviour